# Простая проблема, Python3

Tags: python

```
import pprint
amount = int(input())
commands = []
namespaces = {'global': [],
              'global_path': []}
for i in range(amount):
    commands.append(input().split(' '))
for command in commands:
    if command[0] == 'create':
        namespaces[command[1]] = []
        (1)namespaces[command[1] + '_path'] = namespaces[command[2]+'_path'].copy().append(command[2])
        (2)namespaces[command[1] + '_path'] = namespaces[command[2]+'_path'].copy()
        (2)namespaces[command[1] + '_path'].append(command[2])   
pprint.pprint(namespaces)
```

Здравствуйте!
Когда закомментирована строка (1), то при тесте и вводе построчно:

```
 1. 1 
 2. create one global
```

Выводится то, что ожидалось:

```
{'global': [], 'global_path': [], 'one': [], 'one_path': ['global']}
```

Однако когда закомментированы строки (2), выводится не то, что ожидалось.

```
{'global': [], 'global_path': [], 'one': [], 'one_path': None}
```

Строка (1) и строки (2) эквиваленты, как мне кажется.

В чем я ошибаюсь?
Спасибо!

Comment: Дайте вопросу заголовок, отражающий суть проблемы.

Comment: Какой заголовок вопроса был бы уместен в данном вопросе?

Answer (score 2):

`x.append` ничего не возвращает

```
x = []
print(x.append(0))
```

вывод:

> ```
> None
> ```

можно записать так:

```
namespaces[command[2]+'_path'].copy() + [d[2]]
```

Comment: `%s/\.copy()//g`

Comment: @vp_arth что это?

Comment: Я говорю, что `.copy()` теперь лишний)

Comment: Большое спасибо!